# How can we find the visibility on an element in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

My scenario: after login into my account an interstitial will be opened on the webpage. My use case is if the interstitial is displayed I'll close the interstitial like

```
inter=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/*x-path location/*")

if inter1.is_displayed():
    inter1.click()
```

But for few users interstitial will not be displayed, I've updated my code like below

```
if(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/*x-path location/*").is_displayed()):
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("/*x-path location/*").close()

else:
   (kept my rest of the class part here)
```

But my script is failed with below error

Can some one help me with the suggestions ,thanks in Advance

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/map/area[1]"}
>   Stacktrace:
>       at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/7f/q00y41s11xdfknssfymz3qfc0000gv/T/tmp8w0k6J/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
>       at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///var/folders/7f/q00y41s11xdfknssfymz3qfc0000gv/T/tmp8w0k6J/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:625)

Answer (score 1):

First of all take a look into : [waits methods](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

I suggest that you try this solution :

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((inter1, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Hope that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution for the above usecase :

```
def is_text_present(driver):

try :
    print "This is is_text_present method"
    body = driver.find_element_by_xpath("Your xpath")
    body.click();
except NoSuchElementException, e:
    return False
return True
```